# How to wait untill a page is dim after clicking a button?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to wait until a page is dim(loading) after clicking a button? I tried following options but not succeeded yet. I have to capture transaction timings.

1) Implicit Wait

```
(driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);)
```

2) Explicit Wait

```
(wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 200);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//a[@ardbn='z3Btn_TDS_Next']/div/img)[position()<3]")));)
```

3) One of my own function

```html
public void waitForPageLoaded() { 

ExpectedCondition<Boolean> expectation = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() { public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) { return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"); } }; 

Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30); try { wait.until(expectation); } catch(Throwable error) { fail("Timeout waiting for Page Load Request to complete."); } }
```

[image: Screnshot]

Comment: The the term you used `until a page is dim(loading)` is too broad to be answered here. Can you let us know your exact requirement or Testing step? Thanks.

Comment: When I click a button whole page dims and after the completion of that transaction it comes to normal state. Now what is happening, Page is in dim state and the next transaction started and whole test got failed. I don't want to use sleep or any other specific time gap function otherwise I am not able to capture the actual transaction time.

Comment: From your recent comment I understand you are trying to `capture the actual transaction time` for which Selenium may not be the right tool. You may like to have a look at some other tools e.g. `SoapUI` which is exclusively used for Testing Web Services along with the provision of `Load Test`. Thanks

Comment: Add a script to check for the inivisibility of the Loading button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait till invisibility of Loading box.
Suppose locator/id/xpath of Loading box is id = loader, Then

```
By locator = By.id("loader");
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)  
                    .withTimeout(timeOutInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)                    
                    .pollingEvery(pollingIntervalInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)            
                    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)                     
                    .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class);                    
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
```